# ldapdb: "'NoneType' object is not callable" when adding ldap database to django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, ldap

Running django 1.11 and trying to connect to LDAP server by using django module ldapdb (django-ldapdb==0.8.0):

```
DATABASES = {
    'ldap': {
        'ENGINE': 'ldapdb.backends.ldap',
        'NAME': 'ldap://192.168.1.39/',
    },
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'prot',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'prot',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'geheim',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': 'localhost',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '5432',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    },
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['ldapdb.router.Router']
```

However I get an error in the ldapdb code.

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f4ba61ff840>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nfs/ruben/Projects/prot-zboss/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nfs/ruben/Projects/prot-zboss/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/nfs/ruben/Projects/prot-zboss/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/nfs/ruben/Projects/prot-zboss/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/nfs/ruben/Projects/prot-zboss/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/nfs/ruben/Projects/prot-zboss/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 30, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "/home/nfs/ruben/Projects/prot-zboss/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1284, in check
    errors.extend(cls._check_long_column_names())
  File "/home/nfs/ruben/Projects/prot-zboss/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1699, in _check_long_column_names
    connection = connections[db]
  File "/home/nfs/ruben/Projects/prot-zboss/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 212, in __getitem__
    conn = backend.DatabaseWrapper(db, alias)
  File "/home/nfs/ruben/Projects/prot-zboss/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ldapdb/backends/ldap/base.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(DatabaseWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nfs/ruben/Projects/prot-zboss/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 96, in __init__
    self.client = self.client_class(self)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

The ldapdb 0.8 is the last version and supports django >=1.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

The `django-ldapdb` version has to be at least 0.9.

```
pip install django-ldapdb>=0.9
```

**Old post:**

`django-ldapdb` supports at the moment only the Django version's 1.8-1.10.

So the solution is realy simple:

```
pip install Django==1.10
```

Comment: not true at all, https://github.com/django-ldapdb/django-ldapdb/commit/e6646a42422e5dfe0c2edb02bb2d54fd4595f38f

Comment: Indeed, `django-ldapdb` works now also with `Django 1.10`

Comment: you mean Django 1.11